# Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

**I can't solve this error. Can you help me?**
:Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list..

[image]

Comment: Your smart contract is all fine. It's seems to be a compilation problem. How are you triing to compile your smart contract ? (Remix, Brownies, other ...)

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking here. Please edit your question and include where you get that error and how. Otherwise, your contract looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of Juan Blanco's solidity extension seems borked and was giving me all sorts of wrong "expected" errors. I rolled back to v0.0.141 and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an issue on your OpenZeppelin build. Try direct imports like this:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

If it works, remove existing openzeppelin/contracts and reinstall with `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts`

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work.

Comment: @nacerme same error or something else?

Comment: I got a same error.